# Image looks different on different computers

Tags: jquery, css, image, cross-browser, resolution

I have a problem with my blog where it looks different on other computers (I tested with 4). To be specific, there are two images affected, and they look like this in the code:

```
$('#content').infinitescroll({
           img      : "http://s2.postimg.org/xxwk01if9/466_1.gif" }
```

and

```
background: url('http://s13.postimg.org/6yl9jleo7/who_said_this_hover_for_answer_51fedf2a96537.png') 0 2px no-repeat;
```

Here's an image link where I compare the images on different computers:
[image: screenshot]

The GIF picture is not showing at all on 2 of the computers, and the background one looks different. It's supposed to be transparent but instead it has grey background and is zoomed in.

The strange thing is that I have lots of image posts and buttons with background sprites but only the 2 mentioned images are affected.

It's not a browser issue as it either works fine in all browsers on one computer or not. I don't think it's a resolution issue either as there are no pattern between the 4 computers tested.

I searched and couldn't find anybody with similar issues, only the ones that reported that images are pushed down on another computer or the colors changed a bit.

Comment: It could be a browser cache issue. Have you tried to disable cache on the computers you tested?

Comment: I didn't really disable it but I cleared the cache several time, didn't change anything.